# Waveform file not running under simulation

Tags: quartus

When I click under the button `Run functional Simulation`, I see this error:

```
Determining the location of the ModelSim executable...
Using: C:\altera\13.1\modelsim_ase\win32aloem
To specify a ModelSim executable directory, select: Tools -> Options -> EDA Tool Options
Note: if both ModelSim-Altera and ModelSim executables are available, ModelSim-Altera will be used.

**** Generating the ModelSim Testbench ****
quartus_eda --gen_testbench --check_outputs=on --tool=modelsim_oem --format=verilog ejem_1 -c ejem_1 --vector_source=I:/5 Semestre/Arquitectura Computacional/Ejem_1 - 18-02-15/Waveform1.vwf --testbench_file=I:/5 Semestre/Arquitectura Computacional/Ejem_1 - 18-02-15/simulation/qsim/Waveform1.vwf.vt

Error (23028): Unknown argument "Semestre/Arquitectura". Refer to --help for legal arguments.

Usage:
------

quartus_eda [-h | --help[=] | -v]
quartus_eda  []
quartus_eda -t 
Error.
```

This is the directory of ModelSim-Altera.
I'm working with Quartus 13.1 Cyclone III

```
C:\altera\13.1\modelsim_ase\win32aloem
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Quartus is pretty stupid when it comes to spaces in directory names. Your path has multiple spaces

> .../Arquitectura Computacional/Ejem_1 - 18-02-15/...

Try to build your project inside a no space directory path like

> C:/altera/projects/my_project